# error: _slurm_rpc_node_registration node=xxxxx: Invalid argument

Tags: slurm

I am trying to setup Slurm - I have only one login node (called **ctm-login-01**) and one compute node (called **ctm-deep-01**). My compute node has several CPUs and 3 GPUs.

My compute node keeps being in `drain` state and I cannot for the life of me figure out where to start...

---

### Login node

**sinfo**

```
ctm-login-01:~$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      1  drain ctm-deep-01
```

The reason?

**sinfo -R**

```
ctm-login-01:~$ sinfo -R
REASON               USER      TIMESTAMP           NODELIST
gres/gpu count repor slurm     2020-12-11T15:56:55 ctm-deep-01
```

Indeed, I keep getting these error messages in `/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log`:

**/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log**

```
[2020-12-11T16:17:39.857] gres/gpu: state for ctm-deep-01
[2020-12-11T16:17:39.857]   gres_cnt found:0 configured:3 avail:3 alloc:0
[2020-12-11T16:17:39.857]   gres_bit_alloc:NULL
[2020-12-11T16:17:39.857]   gres_used:(null)
[2020-12-11T16:17:39.857] error: _slurm_rpc_node_registration node=ctm-deep-01: Invalid argument
```

(Notice that I have set `slurm.conf` Debug to `verbose` and also set `DebugFlags=Gres` for more details on the GPU.)

These are the configuration files I have in all nodes and some of their contents...

**/etc/slurm-llnl/* files**

```
ctm-login-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ ls
cgroup.conf  cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf  gres.conf  plugstack.conf  plugstack.conf.d  slurm.conf
ctm-login-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ tail slurm.conf 
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
GresTypes=gpu
NodeName=ctm-deep-01 Gres=gpu:3 CPUs=24 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=12 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ctm-deep-01 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP

# default
SallocDefaultCommand="srun --gres=gpu:1 $SHELL"
ctm-deep-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ cat gres.conf 
NodeName=ctm-login-01 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia0 CPUs=0-23
NodeName=ctm-login-01 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia1 CPUs=0-23
NodeName=ctm-login-01 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia2 CPUs=0-23
ctm-login-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ cat cgroup.conf 
CgroupAutomount=yes 
CgroupReleaseAgentDir="/etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup" 

ConstrainCores=yes 
ConstrainDevices=yes
ConstrainRAMSpace=yes
#TaskAffinity=yes
ctm-login-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ cat cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf 
/dev/null
/dev/urandom
/dev/zero
/dev/sda*
/dev/cpu/*/*
/dev/pts/*
/dev/nvidia*
```

---

### Compute node

The logs in my compute node are the following.

**/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log**

```
ctm-deep-01:~$ sudo tail /var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log 
[2020-12-11T15:54:35.787] Munge credential signature plugin unloaded
[2020-12-11T15:54:35.788] Slurmd shutdown completing
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.433] Message aggregation disabled
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.436] topology NONE plugin loaded
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.436] route default plugin loaded
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.440] task affinity plugin loaded with CPU mask 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.440] Munge credential signature plugin loaded
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.441] slurmd version 19.05.5 started
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.442] slurmd started on Fri, 11 Dec 2020 15:55:53 +0000
[2020-12-11T15:55:53.443] CPUs=24 Boards=1 Sockets=1 Cores=12 Threads=2 Memory=128754 TmpDisk=936355 Uptime=26 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(null)
```

That CPU mask affinity looks weird...

Notice that I have already called `sudo nvidia-smi --persistence-mode=1`. Notice also that the aforementioned `gres.conf` file seems correct:

**nvidia-smi topo -m**

```
ctm-deep-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ sudo nvidia-smi topo -m
        GPU0  GPU1  GPU2  CPU Affinity  NUMA Affinity
GPU0     X    SYS   SYS   0-23          N/A
GPU1    SYS    X    PHB   0-23          N/A
GPU2    SYS   PHB    X    0-23          N/A
```

---

Any other log or configuration I should take a clue from? Thanks!

Comment: is your `gres.conf` file also available in the compute node?

Comment: @CarlesFenoy The file exists in both login and compute `/etc/slurm-llnl`... But indeed, it is weird that `/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log` does not show any messages about the GPU, right? Maybe it is looking at the wrong folder somehow... Could it have to do with cgroups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was all because of a  typo!

```
ctm-deep-01:/etc/slurm-llnl$ cat gres.conf 
NodeName=ctm-login-01 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia0 CPUs=0-23
NodeName=ctm-login-01 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia1 CPUs=0-23
NodeName=ctm-login-01 Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia2 CPUs=0-23
```

Obviously, that should be `NodeName=ctm-deep-01` which is my compute node! Jeez...

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same in `/var/log/slurmctld` after adding a new GPU compute node.

```
[2023-08-10T09:50:19.072] error: _slurm_rpc_node_registration node=c0236: Invalid argument
```

It turns out, I had added the GPUs to `/etc/slurm/gres.conf` after the new node had fully booted:

```
NodeName=c[0236-0237] Name=gpu Type=ampere File=/dev/nvidia0 CPUs=[0-63]
NodeName=c[0236-0237] Name=gpu Type=ampere File=/dev/nvidia1 CPUs=[64-127]
```

An a `sudo systemctl restart slurmctld && sudo scontrol reconfigure` wasn't sufficient.

I restarted `slurmd` on the node and the `slurmctld` log indicated the following, after which the `invalid argument` stopped logging

```
[2023-08-10T09:51:58.765] gres/gpu: count changed for node c0236 from 0 to 2
```

According to [https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.conf.html][SchedMD's gres.conf] documentation, `gres.conf` slurmd is supposed to reread the file when `reconfigure` is used. Perhaps its because we are still on 18.08 and that wasn't added until later.

At an rate, for our new nodes, we needed to restart slurmd after adding the Gres entries.